# Good sites to find textures online?

Tags: website-design, resource-recommendations, texture

I'm always on the lookout for good textures, as they are pretty subtle but can add a lot of life to your site. Recently I found Tileables (http://tileabl.es/) which looks pretty cool.

Can you recommend any other good sites for textures, or make-your-own-texture tutorials?

Comment: http://www.colourlovers.com/ has some cool stuff!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- http://lostandtaken.com/
- http://www.sxc.hu/ (this is a stock
  art site, but does have a lot of
  textures too)
- http://www.textureking.com/
- http://sixrevisions.com/category/freebies/
  (many types of freebies, so you may
  have to look a bit to find the
  textures)
- http://www.bittbox.com/category/freebies
- http://www.grungetextures.com/
- http://www.highresolutiontextures.com/
- http://soundimage.org/

Each of these has different licensing requirements so you'll want to make sure to check those before using anything off these sites.

Answer (score 5):

Check out http://subtlepatterns.com/, I think that's what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

These are geared toward photographic textures for 3D graphics so probably not what you have in mind, but here are a few:

http://mayang.com/textures/

http://www.spiralgraphics.biz/packs/index.htm

http://noctua-graphics.de/english/freetex_e.htm

http://www.cgtextures.com/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.myfreetextures.com has a bit over 1000 free textures and images

Answer (score 1):

There's a new website I've created that is and will be focused around only free textures and images (without requiring attribution). Some seamless, some not, many in 2048x2048 resolution. The available pool of textures will grow over time.

You could check it if you like, it is http://photofree.ga

Thanks!

Comment: Nice, if I could make one suggestion since its your site. I was looking for a download button after clicking on a texture. Like the one I'm glancing at (Dirt) says "Maximum resolution 4864 x 2736" but I can't find where that maximum size is.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for checking it out. To protect website bandwidth from spam bots/mass downloads, a quick registration is required. You don't need to prove your personal information such as name, and can use any E-mail to register.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old link but in case anyone is still looking, www.episcura.com is a nice royalty free texture site that has lots of seamless images, HDRI and some stock photography as well. Worth checking out.